# Excel: If a cell contains two words, how would I use the first letter of the first word and first two letter of the second word?

Tags: excel

Actually, I'm working on a worksheet where the Country code name should be three lowercase letters. if a country has only one word in its name, its code should be the first three letters in that name the code for Germany should be ger. if the name of a country consists of more than one word, its code should consist of the first letter in the first word and the first two letters of the second word. can anyone help, please?

Example:
Cell A1 contains a name e.g. "germany"

A1 needs to output "ger"

If A1 contains "united states"
A1 output should be "ust"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
=LEFT(A1,1)&IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),MID(A1,2,2))
```